# Covariant return types, const-ness, and incomplete classes

Tags: c++, covariance

This code compiles successfully under g++ 6.1 but gives an error with clang 3.8:

```
class C;

class Base {
public:
  virtual const C *getC();
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  virtual       C *getC();
};
```

The error from clang is as follows:

```
$ dev/compilers/linux-x86_64-2.12.2/clang3.8/bin/clang++ -Wall -c testcovariantreturn.cxx
testcovariantreturn.cxx:10:20: error: return type of virtual function 'getC' is not covariant with the return type of the function it overrides ('C' is incomplete)
```

If class C is completely defined rather than forward-declared, there is no error. My understanding is that covariant allows "lesser" cv-qualification (ie, dropping the const from the return type) when overriding a virtual method.

Is clang correct / allowed to require a complete type, and if so, why ? How can having the definition of C available change anything here ?

This is not totally academic, in a large code base I am reluctant to add in unnecessary includes, we try to forward declare as standard practice.

Comment: This code is covariant so ideally it should be accepted. The opposite `const` variance would not be covariant and would support UB modification of originally `const` object. That said (it matters) I don't know what the C++ standard says about it, if anything.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is clang 3.8 bug, specifically [26297](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26297). From [class.virtual], wording from N4594:

> The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to the return type of the overridden function
>   or *covariant* with the classes of the functions. If a function `D::f` overrides a function `B::f`, the return types
>   of the functions are covariant if they satisfy the following criteria:
>   (7.1) — both are pointers to classes, both are lvalue references to classes, or both are rvalue references to
>   classes
>   (7.2) — the class in the return type of `B::f` is the same class as the class in the return type of `D::f`, or is an
>   unambiguous and accessible direct or indirect base class of the class in the return type of `D::f`
>   (7.3) — both pointers or references have the same cv-qualification and the class type in the return type of `D::f`
>   has the same cv-qualification as or less cv-qualification than the class type in the return type of `B::f`.

Having `B::f` return `C const*` and `D::f` return `C*` matches all of these requirements (neither pointer is cv-qualified, and the class type of `D::f` is less cv-qualified than the base), hence it should be allowed.

There is no requirement on completeness; `C` does not need to be complete to check that these criteria.

Comment: Oh, I should have read you answer before commenting. So now I know what the standard says also. Upvoted. :)

Comment: Could you please mention which standard or draft you're quoting from, since the detailed wording has a tendency to change over time. Thanks.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Sure. This part hasn't really changed. The wording from a 2005 draft is basically the same (modulo wording about rvalue references).

Comment: The only semi-relevant clang bug I can find is https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17859 which is actually the reverse of my problem - it claims clang allows dropping const for non-class return types...

Comment: @ChrisMorley It's https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26297, added to the answer.

Comment: @Barry Thanks I guess I suck at searching bugzilla

Answer (score 3):

I also find nothing wrong with your code. It compiles with the head version of clang and all compilers I tried, except clang 3.8 and earlier.

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wo5Y8Yp13TfLzcoL)

The relevant standard text:

> 10.3 note 8:
>
> If the class type in the covariant return type of D::f differs from
>   that of B::f, the *class type* in the return type of D::f shall be
>   *complete* at the point of declaration of D::f *or shall be the class
>   type D.*

The *class type* of the covariant methods must be the same or
complete, but as I understand it const/volatile differences are still considered
 the same *class type*, making your example legal.

Comment: `const` differences matter for covariance. If an override adds `const` to the pointee then it can, within the type system (no cast) return a pointer to an originally `const` object. Client code code using the base class virtual function can then attempt to modify that originally `const` object, = UB.

Comment: I'm not sure of the C++ standard's support here, but regardless of the standard's wording it does matter, very much. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, it matters yes, but what I wanted to referr to was specifically the wording around when *incomplete* types are allowed.

Comment: I didn't know at the time I posted comments above, but [Barry's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38533937/464581) quotes one of the C++ standards on this, and so it's now clear that this answer is wrong (in what it implies).

Comment: Thanks, the demo tool is nice

Comment: Cheers, I added the standard quoute regarding incomplete types I referr to.