# c++ crosswise covariant: return type differs due to incomplete type

Tags: c++, covariance

I am experimenting with covariance and came up with the following example that does at least not compile with clang 11 and on VS2015:

```
class Number {
public:
    virtual ~Number () = default;
    virtual Number const * increment()const = 0;
};

class Even;

class Odd : public Number {
public:
    // error: increment() is not covariant because Even is incomplete
    Even const * increment()const; 
};

class Even : public Number {
public:
    Odd const * increment()const;
};
```

It is related to [Covariant return types, const-ness, and incomplete classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533734/covariant-return-types-const-ness-and-incomplete-classes) but not a duplicate because the constness is the same in both overwritten functions.

Is that even supported by the standard?

Is there a way to get around this problem or any suggestions to achieve a similar behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Covariant return types, const-ness, and incomplete classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533734/covariant-return-types-const-ness-and-incomplete-classes)

Comment: @Kostas That answer is related, but not a dupe. That question is about a clang bug that has since been fixed.

Comment: you could use a std::variant<Even, Odd>, where Even and Odd are just structs, and increment() is just some method that takes a std::variant<Even, Odd>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there may be workaround for what you're trying to achieve, the shown code is invalid.

According to [class.virtual#9](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.virtual#9):

> If the class type in the covariant return type of D​::​f differs from that of B​::​f, the class type in the return type of D​::​f shall be complete at the point of declaration of D​::​f or shall be the class type D. ...

There's an example for this rule in the linked text.

In your case, since the return type of `Odd::increment` is not `Number`, and `Even` is incomplete at the point of declaring `Odd::increment`, the code is ill-formed.

I found the answer in this incorrect, and hence [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38533909/8372853) written by @Brian in response to the question you've linked to.

Comment: ...which makes perfect sense, since how could the compiler verify that the declared return type was valid for covariance, i.e. that it's a subclass of the declared type, without having the full declaration that says so? A forward declaration can only say a type exists but not that it meets certain criteria.

Comment: @underscore_d. It could include the constraint on the symbol produced, and then the linker could give the error though.

Comment: @Kostas Lots of things _could_ be true, but aren't!

Comment: To be fair, you did say "how could the compiler verify ..."? so it *could* be possible ;) But to answer your question @Kostas, given the current language rules, there's not really a way to postpone that check to link-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a similar thing with a non-virtual interface (though it has more lines and seems easier to mess up):

```cpp
class Number {
public:
    virtual ~Number() = default;
    Number const * increment() const { return do_increment(); }
private:
    virtual Number const * do_increment() const = 0;
};

class Even;

class Odd : public Number {
public:
    Even const * increment() const;
private:
    Number const * do_increment() const override;
};

class Even : public Number {
public:
    Odd const * increment() const { return do_increment(); }
private:
    Odd const * do_increment() const override;
};

inline Even const * Odd::increment() const {
    return static_cast<Even const *>(do_increment());
}
```